# FPGA expansion pin problem

Tags: fpga

I am sending a pulse to the expansion pin of an FPGA board which I am monitoring using an oscilloscope.
Why is the oscilloscope reading the pulse in the attached photo? Why it is not a pure square pulse?

[image]

Comment: It looks like it's set for AC coupling? If so try DC and see what it looks like.

Comment: Right, in AC coupling this is wha5 it looks like. Also maybe your probe's ground is not connected to the right place.

Comment: It could also be a probe that has not had its frequency compensation set properly.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a measurement issue. Either you have a broken scope probe (broken signal connection), a disconnected ground wire, or the scope is set to AC coupling.